# Android set String value in String.xml

Tags: android, android-xml

can anybody help me ?? I want to add String value through coding in string.xml  
I am doing this.

```
  String name = getResources().getString(R.string.name);
  if(name.lenght() < 1 ){
      // getResources().setString(R.string.name);??????????????????????

  }
```

My string.xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
    <string name="name"></string>
 </resources>
```

does anybody know how i can add value of name in string.xml though coding. 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The resources are pretty much set in stone, so you can't modify them at runtime. If you need to store some new strings, use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or [`SQLite`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you want to do that.  If you are trying to store a value in a persistent way, take a look at [SharedPrefences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).  Google has a good introduction to it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to modify the resources of an APK during runtime.

Answer (score 4):

You can't edit those resources directly.  You might want to look into sharedpreferences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html or creating your own xml file.

Answer (score 4):

You cant edit a resource or add a resource once the code is compiled. I dont know exactly what setResource does, but once your program is compiled, android builds the gen files which designate a certain amount of space for those variables, changing the variable once written would cause overflow or outofbounds errors with memory. If you want persistent values try using the SharedPrefs, SQL or even your own XML stored within the directory of the app, which you could set to only be readable by your app.